# Windows shortcut - bypass a name changing folder to get to a file

Tags: regex, windows, path, directory, shortcut

I'm usig presets for my keyboard they are bound to the launch file (so the layout changes when the aplication is active). But since Heroes of the Storm launches from a launcher my binds get activated when I launch the launcher (not the game itself) so for it to work I need to go directly to the .exe of the game. Problem is its directory changes with every single little patch.

so:
D:\games\Heroes of the Storm\Versions\Base37569\hots.exe

Base37569 changes to whatever number the current patch build is.

Is there a way (regex?) to bypass the Base37569 folder via a windows shortcut?

Comment: Would it be viable to use a batch file for this ?

Comment: Hard to tell if it would work, but I assume that the preset would work only on the batch file not on the process launched by it.

Comment: I can provide you a batch which searches for the exe, no matter in which directory it was put. But perhaps you need to explain the preset thingy in more detail because I have no complete picture of what you did set up

Comment: Basicly Steelseries uses an app for managing presets.

You search for an app on your pc and pick it. It can be a game or software. Once the process is active the keyboard switches it's layout and macro buttons\settings. This works when alt-tabbing so If the preset app notices you alt tab out of any selected app it changes the preset as well. Thats why I doubt a batch solution will work.because the preset will be set for the batch itself.